# MySQL sum elements of a column

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a table with 3 columns (A,B,C). I want to select some rows from the table and then the MySQL to return a single row having the values added on each column.

```
   A B C
1. 2 2 2
2. 4 4 4
3. 6 7 8
```

MySQL should return in this case, if I select all the three rows:

```
   A   B  C
1. 12  13 14
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
 select sum(A),sum(B),sum(C) from mytable where id in (1,2,3);
```

Answer (score 13):

```
select
  sum(a) as atotal,
  sum(b) as btotal,
  sum(c) as ctotal
from
  yourtable t
where
  t.id in (1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
select sum(a), sum(b), sum(c)
from your_table
```