# How to add numbers in a column with phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, addition, cumulative-sum

I have a table called products, it has a column called products_price with 10000+ different prices, I want to add all the prices together. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most SQL implementations (including MySQL) support special select operators. In your case, you'd do something like

```
SELECT SUM('products_price') from 'products';
```

Easy :)

by the way, I don't know what you've googled, but really, this solution kind of hits you right in the face as soon as you type "Mysql column sum" into googles search bar.

Comment: it doesnt work, error  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; ''products'' at line 1

Comment: works fine for me; compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586040/mysql-sum-elements-of-a-column

Comment: nothing to do with it. Are you sure you're actually don't have a typo somewhere.

Comment: I copied and pasted your command so no typo.  the table is called products and the column I want to sum is called products_price. I just want to add all the prices together in that column. thanks

Comment: try removing the `'`.

Comment: This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.

Comment: yes without the quotes it works but gave an error, anyway now I have the total. thanks