# PHP mysqli Select Add field

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id | user_id | credits
----------------------
1  | 2       | 300
2  | 2       | 200
3  | 4       | 100
```

I need a select or way to add the credits from a specific user id

The select would be:

```
SELECT credit FROM myTable WHERE user_id ='2'
```

The result I would need in this case would be **500**

How can I do this?

Comment: This is a pretty trivial question. Quick googling for "mysql sum column" would have saved you some time and yielded useful results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql sum elements of a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586040/mysql-sum-elements-of-a-column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [SUM()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) in your query will solve the issue.

```
SELECT SUM(`credits`) AS `total` FROM `myTable` WHERE `user_id` =2
```

Since you specify PHP tag, the below code will help you.

```
$mysqli=mysqli_connect("hostname","username","password","databasename");
$query = "SELECT SUM(`credits`) AS `total` FROM `myTable` WHERE `user_id` =2";
$processquery = $mysqli->query($query);
$result = $processquery->fetch_assoc();
echo $result['total'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sum()`

```
SELECT sum(credit) as sum_credit
FROM myTable
WHERE user_id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregate function `SUM()`:

```
SELECT SUM(credit) as TotalCredit
FROM myTable 
WHERE user_id='2'
```

Read more about aggregate functions [**here**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by summing the total of the credit column. Check out the MySQL [reference manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) for the official instructions.

```
SELECT SUM(credit) AS credit_total
FROM myTable
WHERE user_id = 2
```

You use the `AS` keyword to assign a name to your column, then in PHP you can access this column as you would any other by name, just using `credit_total`. E.g:

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(credit) AS credit_total
    FROM myTable
    WHERE user_id = 2";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['credit_total']; // Will output 500
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [SUM()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) in mysql

```
SELECT SUM(credit) as totalcredit FROM myTable WHERE user_id ='2'
```

will return you matched result sum according to condition

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(credit) as total from myTable where user_id = '2'
```