# How to get count of a particular item in mysql table using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, select, count

I am tried to get count of a particular item from mysql table using c#.but i got nothing

My code

```
string Batch = textBox8.Text;
string batchnumber = ("SELECT COUNT [Batch_No] FROM Orders where Batch_No='" + Batch + "'");
```

orders is my table and batch_no is the column and i want to get the count of particular batch number in the table.How can i do this?

Comment: "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Orders where Batch_No='" + Batch + "'"

Comment: @Kami:I need to get the count of Batch_no

Comment: Then use SUM function on the Batch_No column. There is a post that might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586040/mysql-sum-elements-of-a-column

Comment: Count only gives you a count of records whereas SUM will give you a sum of the selected column (numerical of course).

Answer (score 0):

Change `COUNT [Batch_No]` to `COUNT(Batch_No)`. It will work.

Try this:

```
string Batch = textBox8.Text;
string batchnumber = ("SELECT COUNT(Batch_No) FROM Orders WHERE Batch_No='" + Batch + "'");
```