# MYSQL - Finding the sum of column for all distinct fields of a different column?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table `weather` that looks something like this:

```
country | occurences 
USA     |  5 
UK      |  1 
BOL     |  1
USA     |  2 
UK      |  1
```

and this table `weatherOccurences` is what I want to generate:

```
country | occurenceTotal
USA     | 7 
UK      | 2
BOL     | 1
```

Basically, for every distinct country I want to calculate all the occurences for it... but I'm not sure how to do that. I tried:

```
INSERT INTO weatherOccurences(`occurenceTotal`)
SELECT SUM(occurences) from weather w1 
JOIN weatherOccurences w2 
ON w1.country = w2.country
```

However, instead of giving me the occurence count of each country, it just took a sum of all the occurences ever... and appended it to a new row at the end. How would I do the former? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

[edit] would I have to use `UPDATE` and `SET` for this?

Comment: So you've got keywords like SUM, COLUMN, and MYSQL. I would have thought that would be enough to divine an answer without our assistance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql sum elements of a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586040/mysql-sum-elements-of-a-column)

Comment: The only thing you seem to have missed is the **`GROUP BY`** clause.  Add `GROUP BY country` to the end of your query, and add the `country` column to the SELECT list (and to the list of columns in the INSERT).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to group by country, insert that country and select that country:

```
INSERT INTO weatherOccurences(country, occurenceTotal)
SELECT   country, SUM(occurences) 
from     weather
GROUP BY country
```