# Add the number gotten from a db

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I collected data from a database and the data is based upon user id, ie I select data from database table based on a user id. Now the selected result has some value (*numbers*); how do I check if that total sum of the number is equal to a certain amount?

Using Laravel 5.4, I query my db as follows:

```
 $money = $DBTable::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

Now I have a column called `cash` how do I get the total sum of the cash column?
What is the code for that since the result is an object I do a foreach loop

```
 foreach ($money as $key => $value) {
     count($money->cash);
 }
```

this will return the number count of the value:

```
 foreach ($money as $key => $value) {
     echo $earn->earned_amount + $earn->earned_amount;  
 }
```

This will add up individual values to themselves, so please can anyone tell me how this is done?

Comment: Fred please read what i wrote carefully dont be quick to reply. I want to count the value gotten from my column

Comment: Say user have 10k from row 1 20k from two etc how do i add this column from row one, two ..

Comment: Why did you do that. you dont have the answer why would you answer.

Comment: Possibly this would help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586040/mysql-sum-elements-of-a-column SUM mysql keyword

Comment: if that is right is it possible to do that in laravel

Comment: I think it worked but is done in Laravel

Comment: Laravel, not sure never used it. the SUM statement is part of the SQL langauge so should be independant of your PHP framework. Just try it. Experiment

Comment: Ok thanks I would look for the Laravel alternative

Comment: DB::table('table name')
                ->where('id', Auth::user()->id)
                ->sum('cash');

Comment: Can you show your table structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. The Query builder way (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#aggregates)

   DB::table('table name')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id) ->sum('cash');
2. The eloquent way (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sum)

   Auth::user()->cashTransactions->pluck('cash')->sum('price');

I assumed you table $DBTable has a model attached to it and that you have a relationship defined between the table's model and the user model

To define  relationship you do:

in User model:

```
public function cashTransactions()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\CashTransactions');
}
```

in CashTransactions model:

```
public function user()
    {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

Edit: you can also define relationships in a model with the same model (self relationship)