# Mysql query - Issue

Tags: mysql

I am facing 1 issue with MySql query:

```
select sum(h.total_rooms) as total_rooms from reservation_details as rd LEFT JOIN hotels as h ON rd.hotel_id = h.id left join `chains` as `c` on `c`.`id` = `h`.`chain_id` where YEAR(rd.created_at) = 2016 and MONTH(rd.created_at) = 5 and rd.status >= 50 and h.chain_id = 2 GROUP BY rd.hotel_id
```

Above query returns :

```
total_rooms
48216
7700
13250
```

But 
I need sum of the query.

Comment: Use sum function. sum(h.total_rooms) as total_rooms

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql sum elements of a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586040/mysql-sum-elements-of-a-column)

Comment: Please check my updated query @Satish Saini

Comment: Too broad title (and text-like "1" in the content)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use sum() function like this and use [ROLLUP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) with your query.

```
select sum(h.total_rooms) as total_rooms from reservation_details as rd 
LEFT JOIN hotels as h ON rd.hotel_id = h.id 
left join `chains` as `c` on `c`.`id` = `h`.`chain_id` 
where YEAR(rd.created_at) = 2016 and MONTH(rd.created_at) = 5 
and rd.status >= 50 and h.chain_id = 2 GROUP BY rd.hotel_id 
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: I already did @Satish Saini.
But no luck, it showing wrong data

Comment: @RakeshTripathi What do you mean wrong data? If above rows are coming in response and we need to sum it then this function should work fine.

Comment: Using SUM() returns me
total_rooms
48216<br>
7700<br>
13250

Comment: @RakeshTripathi Check my updated answer. You can use Rollup with your query. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Nope its not working, it was throwing same result as above. @Satish Saini

Comment: @RakeshTripathi can you please email me your table dump so I can check it here at my end?