# PHP + MySQL calculate products price

Tags: php, mysql

I need to know how I can get the sum of a column in a MySQL database using PHP

This is a list of products in a DB and each one has a different price, so I want to calculate the sum and show them somewhere on my panel page. How can I do this and store the result in a variable?

[image: MyPHPAdmin image showing the price column]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql sum elements of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586040/mysql-sum-elements-of-a-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can completely handle it in the MySQL query:

```
SELECT SUM(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Using PDO

```
$stmt = $handler->prepare("SELECT SUM(value) AS value_sum FROM codes");
$stmt->execute();

$row = $handler->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$sum = $row->value_sum;
```

Comment: I did used fetchObject() instead of fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); and its work Thanks