# How to SUM Column by Column MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I need sum column by column in MySQL.

First `SUM(column_1)` and show your TOTAL in final row.

Second `SUM(column_2)` and show your TOTAL in final row.

Comment: Hey Rudieron, welcome to SO! Please make sure you read up the following: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 3):

Use this command to perform aggregation in Mysql.

```
select sum(A) as TotalA, sum(B) as TotalB ,sum(C) as TotalC from mytable
```

for the last line

```
LIMIT 1  // <--- Add
```

**Also :** I found this while looking for a better result for you.
[MySql sum elements of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586040/mysql-sum-elements-of-a-column)

Comment: You're welcome. Please choose my answer correctly and close the question.