# Adding all values from output SQL

Tags: sql

So, i have a query which looks like this:

```
SELECT sum(distinct 101-players.position) as points from players
INNER JOIN clubs ON players.id_club=clubs.id_club 
GROUP BY clubs.club
ORDER BY points desc LIMIT 10  OFFSET 10;
```

And it gives me back:

```
222
148
136
94
78
53
11
33
34
51
```

Is there any way that this query will give me back added value? Just number 860.

Kindly please help me :/

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are really using.  (2) Explain how "860" is calculated.

Comment: @GordonLinoff 860 == sum of all numbers, so I guess it's just a plain sum without group by.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySql sum elements of a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586040/mysql-sum-elements-of-a-column)

Comment: `sum(sum(distinct 101-players.position)) over ()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just sum all the points you got from your query:

```
select sum(points) from (
SELECT sum(distinct 101-players.position) as points from players
INNER JOIN clubs ON players.id_club=clubs.id_club 
GROUP BY clubs.club
ORDER BY points desc LIMIT 10  OFFSET 10) t
```